# Need help retrieving Deep values from Hashtable in Powershell

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, hashtable

I kinda need help retrieving deep values from HashTable.

My Situation: I wrote a C# executable which gives me data in JSON format that I stored in a variable **$Result**.
I'm able to fetch and process all fields of **$Result** except nested HashTable called **Properties** and its keys (**Locations**). I just need to list the cities which are mentioned in the HashTable called **Properties**

At the minute I'm able to get the Locations Key as shown below

```html
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $Result.Properties.Locations
City=NewYork,Country=USA,Year=2001;City=Seattle,Country=USA,Year=2002;City=Miami,Country=USA,Year=2010;City=SanJose,Country=USA,Year=2009

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

**Expected Output**:

```html
NewYork
Seattle
Miami
SanJose
```

**Properties Hashtable**

```html
[Properties]@
{
    accountExpires=Never;
    AccountLockedOut=False;
    mail=JamesBond@internationalspy.com;
    cn=Tom Cruise; 
    codePage=0; 
    countryCode=0; 
    displayName=Tom Cruise;
    employeeID=743355; 
    Enabled=True; 
    givenName=Tom; 
    instanceType=4; 
    lastLogoff=12/31/1600 4:00:00 PM; 
    lastLogon=3/27/2020 7:52:36 AM; 
    lastLogonTimestamp=5/25/2020 12:47:07 PM; 
    lockoutTime=12/31/1600 4:00:00 PM; 
    logonCount=4; 
    mail=jamesbond@InternalActor.com;
    Locations=City=NewYork,Country=USA,Year=2001;City=Seattle,Country=USA,Year=2002;City=Miami,Country=USA,Year=2010;City=SanJose,Country=USA,Year=2009
}
```

I need to get the fetch the list of cities which are nested with the above Hashtable.
I just want the list of cities so that I can further apply my business logic and proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some more alternatives for you:

**split and replace:**

```
($Result.Properties.Locations -split '[;,]' | Where-Object { $_ -match '^City=' }) -replace '^City='
```

**split and ConvertFrom-StringData**

```
($Result.Properties.Locations -split '[;,]' | ConvertFrom-StringData).City
```

**iterate over matches**

```
$match = ([regex]'(?i)City=([^,]+)').Match($Result.Properties.Locations)
while ($match.Success) { 
    $match.Groups[1].Value
    $match = $match.NextMatch()
}
```

All result in

```
NewYork
Seattle
Miami
SanJose
```

Answer (score 2):

As the Data is no json Data you will not be able to use the internal powerhsell json cmdlets to manipulate the data. As im not aware of any internal powershell object that can handle your structure out of the box I do recommend to extract the data via .net regex:

```
$psString = '[Properties]@
{
    accountExpires=Never;
    AccountLockedOut=False;
    mail=JamesBond@internationalspy.com;
    cn=Tom Cruise; 
    codePage=0; 
    countryCode=0; 
    displayName=Tom Cruise;
    employeeID=743355; 
    Enabled=True; 
    givenName=Tom; 
    instanceType=4; 
    lastLogoff=12/31/1600 4:00:00 PM; 
    lastLogon=3/27/2020 7:52:36 AM; 
    lastLogonTimestamp=5/25/2020 12:47:07 PM; 
    lockoutTime=12/31/1600 4:00:00 PM; 
    logonCount=4; 
    mail=jamesbond@InternalActor.com;
    Locations=City=NewYork,Country=USA,Year=2001;City=Seattle,Country=USA,Year=2002;City=Miami,Country=USA,Year=2010;City=SanJose,Country=USA,Year=2009
}
'
$extract = [regex]::Match($psString, 'Locations=(.*)').Groups[1].Value
$extract = [regex]::Matches($extract, 'City=([^,]*)')
$extract | foreach {echo $_.Groups[1].Value}
```

gives the desired output.